# Interactive election results charts

Tags: united-states, presidential-election

Is anyone aware of a site with interactive maps where the real-time results of the 2020 US presidential election results can be found?

I find many claims of there being some specific vote counts being reported at given times throughout counting.  **For example**, I'm looking for a way to verify results such as what was reported in Georgia as of 11:00 PM ET on election night.

**Edit**  I want to see what the breakout was as the counting progressed, more in relation to as the total reported neared 100% vs. at a specific point in time.

Comment: What purpose would this serve when there are so many votes that couldn't be legally counted until after the polls closed on election night?

Comment: I'm sure someone already asked this here, although on such a tone that the q was deleted together with my answer. You could look at related q on Skeptics for some sources: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/49886/did-a-drop-and-roll-phenomena-expose-that-the-2020-election-was-stolen

Comment: @JoeW  To understand the situation.  Many claims are being made as to how the numbers changed.  I suspect many are misremembered or falsifications, but only having individuals' recollections--usually ones they wanted to be the case--having the data can help understand.

Comment: Numbers changing because they counted more votes and reported a new total don't really have much meaning. In this case as they counted and reported in person voting before mail in voting that caused the votes to look like they favored on candidate over the other because of how people voted. So they don't have much meaning.

Comment: @JoeW  They have a great deal of meaning...in the context you just laid out.  And that is why I ask.  People are speaking of statistically unlikely to mathematically impossible outcomes.  For example with 98% of the vote in, Trump was ahead by 3% then lost.  ASSUMING the 98% to be true only error corrections or nefarious manipulations occurred.  I believe these assertions to be inaccurate, say the outstanding margin was 94%.  Due to dems being more likely to use mail-ins, that is not so implausible anymore.  I want to build my case on the actual numbers.

Comment: I think that is a different question if you are wondering what the vote count stood at when it was at a certain percentage of votes cast. However in this case when you have votes coming in from multiple sources and some of those votes where not even legally allowed to be counted I would argue that it is hard to say how accurate the vote counted percentage is at any given time. At best they can go off number of registered voters but that has its own issues. Looking for numbers at a given point in time doesn't have any real value as it has been shown over the years that it can change.

Comment: @JoeW It doesn't solve the entirety, but proof of validity can't really be done without a very different set of investigation and whether or not those should have been legal is, again, not a numbers question.  What this does is disproves that the ONLY possibilities are errors and fraud.  It adds back in the plausibility that the outcome was legitimate.

Comment: I think you are still missing my point. The numbers that get reported tend to get reported from similar areas so it is not unusual for blocks of votes to get reported for a single candidate because the areas they reported support them while higher population areas that support a different candidate get reported later. Worrying about what the numbers in Georgia are at 11pm when there are massive population centers that haven't started reporting many votes yet doesn't do you any good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118842/discussion-between-john-spiegel-and-joe-w).

Comment: If you are trying to argue with people saying nonsense about the % being such and such at X time, I wouldn't waste your time on them. The only count that matters is the final one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of such maps. There are graphs that show how the vote came in but they do not show the exact time nor the exact voteshare, such as the ones from [The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/11/03/us/elections/results-georgia-president.html) and [FiveThirtyEight](https://fivethirtyeight.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/LB-ga-update-01.png?w=700).

However, one of the ways to obtain results at a specific time would perhaps be to rewatch the full election night coverage online.

For instance, for Georgia, at 11:00 PM ET, the results according to [NBC News' live coverage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQba647SNmM) are as follows:

> [image]

Also, these numbers are backed up by The New York Times. Results below are from NYT at 11:09 PM ET:

> [image]

Comment: Thank you and apologies for unclear wording.  I've edited the question to hopefully clarify.